# How can I put two boxes right next to each other that have the exact same size?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am new to Latex and Tikz and I am struggling to make two boxes right next to each other that have the exact same size.

[image]
(So like this but without spacing in between and without the 123 node being bigger)

Right now I have come up with this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} 

\usepackage{xstring}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    roundnode/.style={circle, draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick, exact size=5mm},
    squarednode/.style={rectangle, draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick, minimum size=5mm},
    ]
    %Nodes
    \node[squarednode]      (maintopic)                              {2};
    \node[squarednode]      (mynode)            [right=of maintopic] {123};
    %Connections
    \draw[] (maintopic) (mynode);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about `minimum width=2em, minimum height=5mm` instead of `minimum size=5mm`?

Comment: Using `right of` is what gives you the space. For the second node, try `[anchor=west,...] at (main topic.east) {123} `...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

Small variation of @SebGlav abswer:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0pt,
square/.style = {draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick, 
                 minimum height=1.2em, minimum width=3em, % <---
                 outer sep=0pt},                          % <---
    ]
%Nodes
\node[square]   (maintopic) {2};
\node[square, right=of maintopic] (mynode) {123};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Play with `positioning` abilities and nodes `anchor`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} 

\begin{document}
    

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        squarednode/.style={rectangle, draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick, minimum width=\nodewidth},
        ]
        
        \def\nodewidth{5mm}

        \node[squarednode]      (maintopic)                              {2};
        \node[squarednode]      (mynode)            [right= 0.5*\nodewidth of maintopic.center,anchor=west] {123};
        
        \def\nodewidth{10mm}

        \node[squarednode,below=1cm of maintopic.center]      (maintopic2)                              {2};
        \node[squarednode]      (mynode2)            [right= 0.5*\nodewidth of maintopic2.center,anchor=west] {123};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: nodes without space between them]

Answer (score 5):

If you want square nodes, use `geometry.shape` `regular polyogon`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    squarednode/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=4, 
    draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick, minimum size=15mm, inner sep=0pt},
    ]
    %Nodes
    \node[squarednode](maintopic) {2};
    \node[squarednode, anchor=west](mynode) at (maintopic.east)  {123};
    %Connections (which ones? they are close together...
    \draw[] (maintopic) (mynode);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, there is no such a key as `exact size`.

To set the color you can pass an argument to a style:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    squarednode/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=4,
    draw=#1!60, fill=#1!5, very thick, minimum size=15mm, inner sep=0pt},
    squarednode/.default=blue,
    ]
    %Nodes
    \node[squarednode=red](maintopic) {2};
    \node[squarednode, anchor=west](mynode) at (maintopic.east)  {123};
    %Connections (which ones? they are close together...
    \draw[] (maintopic) (mynode);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible with geometric shapes to set the color of the rectangle's sides individually?

Answer (score 4):

This seems a good opportunity to exploit the capabilities of Ti*k*Z's `shapes.multipart` library.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

%% |=====8><-----| %%

\tikzset{
    myboxes/.style={
        rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split parts=2,
        draw=blue!60,fill=blue!10, very thick,minimum height=1.5em,text width=3em,align=center
    }
}

\tikzset{
    mycolorboxes/.style={
        rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split parts=2,
        rectangle split part fill={blue!10,red!10},
        draw=blue!60,very thick,minimum height=1.5em,text width=3em,align=center
    }
}

%% |=====8><-----| %%

\NewDocumentCommand{\boxnums}{mm}{%
    \tikz{\node[myboxes]{#1\nodepart{two}#2};}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\colorboxnums}{mm}{%
    \tikz{\node[mycolorboxes]{#1\nodepart{two}#2};}
}

%% |=====8><-----| %%

\begin{document}

\boxnums{9}{1234}

\colorboxnums{4}{11235}

\end{document}
```

[image: example of multipart box]

Answer (score 4):

Do you really need  a sledgehammer to crack a nut? It can be done with `\fcolorbox` and the `eqparbox` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand\eqcolorbox[4][C]{\setlength{\fboxrule}{1.5pt}\setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt}%
\fcolorbox{#2}{#3}{\eqmakebox[#1]{#4}}}

\begin{document}

\eqcolorbox{MediumBlue}{Lavender}{23}\hspace{-\fboxrule}\eqcolorbox{MediumBlue}{Lavender}{12345}

\end{document}
```

[image]